# Angular material template website

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there any website that is similar to `bootsnipp.com` (for Bootstrap) But of course dedicated for `angular-material`?

Comment: I wonder whether there is something out there?

Answer (score 1):

You have [`CodePen`](http://codepen.io/collection/XExqGz/) and [Their orginal site](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/) (which you may already know of).

If you search for ideas to new design possibilities I would also recommend [Google MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/showcase/index.html) (Material Design Lite). They relay more on more CSS, but got almost the same rules for design.

Comment: Yep, Ive seen Google MDL. However I dont want to include that since Im already using angular-material.

Comment: Yeah, I would just stick with one of them too, but I was pointing to the concepts of the design as they share some of the same solutions ;)

Comment: I have searched a while now and do only see articles and tutorials - no codebases with plain angular-material. Comment if you find anything, I'm interested too!